# Grails 1.0 to 1.3 - Speed Increase?

Tags: performance, grails, groovy

I am trying to justify an upgrade of Grails from 1.0 to 1.3 and am wondering if I can add speed to the benefits.  Does anyone have any empirical data on the subject?

Comment: Anything like this is going to depend on exactly what your codebase does, and can't be answered as a generality. Voting to close as "not a real question", although it could also be closed for "subjective and argumentative".

Comment: @Ken White - Assume a simple CRUD system.  That is not enough information to say if a newer version goes faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on a lot of things of course, and you haven't shared many details of your application. If you're using 1.0.3 or earlier, the default was to eagerly load collections and this bug was fixed in 1.0.4, so upgrading to 1.3 will certainly be faster when working with collections that you expect to be lazy-loaded. There have also been significant performance increases in GSP rendering in 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3. In addition GSPs are now precompiled when building a war file, so deployed applications use a lot less permgen.

Groovy has also gotten a lot faster from the 1.5.x that was used in 1.0 to the 1.7.8 that's used in 1.3.7.

There are other non-performance-related reasons to upgrade too. These include access to newer features that didn't exist in 1.0, plugins that won't work in older versions, and better IDE support.

Answer (score 1):

That's a big jump and I don't for sure how much performance benefit you will see but it's certainty a lot. However, you should consider other advantages for the upgrade -- bug fixes, new features, easier gorm query, able to use latest plugins, etc.

FYI: We did upgrade from 1.* to 1.3, and it's requires some code change. Not a lot but take it as opportunity to clean and cut down on code count.